# Why INSERT does not work with InnoDB in Windows with Wamp Server?

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, wampserver, myisam

I am using Wamp Server in Windows 8 and when I choose InnoDB for my table my INSERT query does not work. But if I choose MyISAM it works fine. Dows anyone know why? When execute the query it does not give any error message but it also does not add entry I want.

Here is my table structure ans PHP function for insert:

```
function insertItems($JsonString) {

    error_log("insertItems: giriş\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
    $array = json_decode($JsonString, true);

    if ($array) {
        $name = $array['name'];
        $category = $array['category'];
        $imageurl = $array['imageurl'];
        $price = $array['price'];
        $ingredient = $array['ingredient'];
        $cookingTime = $array['cookingTime'];
        $recipe = $array['recipe'];
        error_log($JsonString . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($name . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($category . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($imageurl . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($price . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($ingredient . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($cookingTime . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        error_log($recipe . "\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO yiyecekler VALUES ('','İmam Bayıldı', '30.0', '3 adet patlıcan', '45', 'Kebaplar', 'Anlatması çok uzun sürer şimdi :)')");
        //$stmt->bind_param('sssdsis', $name, $category, $imageurl, $price, $ingredient, $cookingTime, $recipe);
        //$stmt->bind_param('sssdsis', "asd", "asd", "asd",14.0, "asd", 123, "dsadsa");

        if($stmt->execute()){
            $stmt->fetch();
            $stmt->commit();
            error_log("INSERT Başarılı!", 3, "c:/php.log");
        } else {
            error_log("INSERT FAIL!", 3, "c:/php.log");
        }

        error_log($db->connect_error, 3, "c:/php.log");

        /* check connection */
        if ($db->connect_errno) {
            error_log($db->connect_error, 3, "c:/php.log");
            exit();
        }

        //mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'restoran');
        //mysql_query('INSERT INTO yiyecekler VALUES (null,"asdas", "asdasd", "asdasd", "14.0", "asdasdas", "15", "asdasd")');
        //error_log($stmt->error_list, 3, "c:/php.log");
    } else {
        error_log("stmt = NULL", 3, "/c:/php.log");
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is not answerable in its present form.  You would need to include information about your table structures, and the `INSERT` you are trying to perform.

Comment: Have you checked your references?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work", what error message are you getting?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have added the details.

Comment: @ChristianMark what you mean by check your references? I did not get it?

Comment: @Pekka when I execute the query. It works without any error but it does nothing.

Comment: Check for errors after the `prepare()` call.  `if (!$stmt) echo $this->db->error;`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I have checked that $stmt is valid.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly check for errors, after the prepare and execute statements you need to check for success or failure and display any useful error infomation.

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO yiyecekler 
          VALUES ('','İmam Bayıldı', '30.0', '3 adet patlıcan', '45', 
                  'Kebaplar', 'Anlatması çok uzun sürer şimdi :)')");

if ( $stmt === FALSE ) {
    $code    =  $stmt->errorCode();
    $errInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
    error_log("PREPARE of INSERT query, FAILED\nCode: $code ErrorMessage: $errInfo\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
} else {
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $stmt->commit();
        error_log("INSERT Başarılı!", 3, "c:/php.log");
    } else {
        $code    =  $stmt->errorCode();
        $errInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        error_log("INSERT FAIL!\nCode: $code ErrorMessage: $errInfo\n", 3, "c:/php.log");
    }
}
```

This may give you a clue to where the problem lies.

**EDIT:**

If there are errors they should be reported but can you check your php.ini to make sure you have the following parameters set:

Use the Wampmanager menus to make sure you are editing the correct file !!!

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
log_errors = On
error_log = "c:/wamp/logs/php_error.log"
```

they are not all in that same place in the .ini file but thay all should be in there somewhere and set as above.

Also check the `apache error log` also viewed via the wampmanager menus, make sure that there are no error message in the apache log and then run `phpinfo` from the Wamp Homepage, checking the PDO libraries are loaded.

**ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:**

Maybe you have more than one MySQL installed on your system. Often WampServer users have tried to install Apache and MySQL manually before giving up and using WAMPServer.

Check this by looking at the services that you have installed.

```
START -> Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
```

Look for these 2 services

1. MYSQL
2. wampmysql

If you have a `MYSQL` service and it is in the `started state` that is not the one installed by WAMPServer. So uninstall it, after making sure you have a backup of your schema.

Then uninstall that version of MySQL, using the standard `add remove programs`

Also check for a `my.ini` file anywhere in the `C:\windows\` folder structure, if you find one delete it as this is probably pointing wamps wampmysql to a different `\data\` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for correct error checking tip. But it stil does not give any error and it still does not insert.